# Append DIV after AJAX Success

Tags: javascript

As the title states, I am trying to perform a simple task of when my ajax post successfully completes my database query, I would like to add the word "Success" into an empty DIV using the AJAX success option. I can't figure out how to get that text to appear. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my working AJAX post:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#noteForm").submit(function(){
            // prevent native form submission here
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#noteForm').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "actionpages/link_notes_action.cfm?id=2",
                success: function() {
                    $(".response").append($( "Success" ) );
                }    
            });
            return false;           
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a div in my page with id of "response" that is nested inside the div of my form.

```
<!--- Modal HTML embedded directly into document --->
<div id="LinkNotes#id#" style="display:none;">
    <p>These are the notes for: #link_description#</p>
    <form id="noteForm">
        <textarea id="noteText" name="noteText" cols="45" rows="10">#notes#</textarea><br />

        <input name="submit" id="submitForm" type="submit" value="Update"><div class="response" id="response"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="#get_dashboard_links.ID#">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

So close!

Since you just want to append a string, you only have to pass that string to `.append`.

Replace:

```
.append($( "Success" ) );
```

With:

```
.append("Success");
```

`$("Success")` looks for a `<Succes />` tag, which it doesn't find, resulting in an empty set that's being appended.
As you can probably imagine, appending "nothing" doesn't do particularly much ;-)

Comment: Or better `.append($("<div>").text("Success"));` - if you want to append DIV as you type in subject of question.

Comment: @Cockootec: _"I would like to add the word "Success" into an empty DIV"_. I think the OP means `<div class="response" id="response"></div>` with that _"empty div"_.

Comment: I still do not get anything on my screen after the ajax call when I make the edits Cerbrus suggests. Does it matter there is no content in this div to start with?

Comment: Is the `success` function being called?

Comment: How can I confirm that?

Comment: Place a `console.log('something')` in `success: function() {`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288984/append-div-after-ajax-success)

Apparently removing

```
dataType: 'json',
```

from my script fixed it.